# NGINX try_files does not execute script

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Hello I have this in Nginx config file

```
location ~* ^/storage/(.+)$ {
        try_files $uri                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                  /thumb.php?$query_string
                  /images/no-photo.jpg;
    }
```

I want to check if an image exists in storage folder if no, run thumb generating script and return image if thumb.php found the original image. If there is no original image i want Nginx to return no-photo.jpg.

But in this case of configuration Nginx skips thumb.php and shows only no-photo.jpg without running the script.

When I remove last portion "/images/no-photo.jpg", thumb.php was run.

Comment: How does Nginx test "If there is no original image"? Can you construct a path to the original image from `$uri` or does `thumb.php` return a 404 status?

Comment: Yes I can construct original image path from $uri and if thumb.php can't find image it returns 404 status

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your requirement, you could check the response from `thumb.php` and on a status 404, return the jpeg.

For example:

```
location /storage/ {
    try_files $uri /thumb.php?$args;
}
location = /thumb.php {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass ...;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 =200 /images/no-photo.jpg;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.